# How to select records that have multiple values in sql?

Tags: sql

The code below returns the count of subscription_plan_ids for a given user that has multiple. However, I would like it to return the actual subscription_plan_ids instead of just the count.

```
Example:
user_id,subscription_plan_id
1,1
1,3


SELECT
  user_id, COUNT(DISTINCT subscription_plan_id), MIN(created_at), MAX(created_at)
FROM
  subscriptions
WHERE 
  created_at BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-01-31'
GROUP BY
  user_id
HAVING
  COUNT(DISTINCT subscription_plan_id) > 1
;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To return all the subscription plan IDs in one row, use GROUP_CONCAT:

```
SELECT user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT subscription_plan_id), MIN(created_at), MAX(created_at)
FROM
  subscriptions
WHERE 
  created_at BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-01-31'
GROUP BY
  user_id
HAVING
  COUNT(DISTINCT subscription_plan_id) > 1
```

To return them in multiple rows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id, subscription_plan_id, created_at
FROM subscriptions s
WHERE user_id IN (
    SELECT user_id
    FROM subscriptions
    WHERE 
      created_at BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-01-31'
    GROUP BY
      user_id
    HAVING
      COUNT(DISTINCT subscription_plan_id) > 1)
AND created_at BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-01-31'
ORDER BY user_id, created_at
```

Comment: what if I just want to return them in multiple rows?

Comment: perfect! I'll select this!

Comment: BTW, you don't need `DISTINCT` if `user_id, subscription_plan_id` is already unique in the table.

Comment: I have another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23433448/how-to-return-a-count-of-a-group-concat-in-sql that is somewhat related :)