# How to return a count of a group_concat in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

The query below returns all of different subscriptions a user has. In another column, I would like to return the count of how many times a given subscription occurs. Any advice on how do this?

I tried including

```
COUNT(GROUP_CONCAT(subscription_plan_id))
```

but it doesn't work.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(subscription_plan_id)
FROM
  subscriptions
WHERE 
  created_at BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-01-31'
GROUP BY
  user_id
HAVING
  COUNT(subscription_plan_id) > 1
```

Desired output:

```
group_concat...count
1,2,3...2
2,3...5
```

Comment: Please show sample data and the desired result. I'm not really sure what you want.

Comment: The above just counts the number of subscriptions each user has. I want to a count of how many times a given subscription path occurs. How many times does a user have subscription_plan_id 1 and 2?

Comment: I still don't understand. How does `2,3` result in `5` as the count? Please show the input data and the desired output. Best would be to make a sqlfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Just put the `count()` in the `select`:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(subscription_plan_id), COUNT(subscription_plan_id) as NumSubs
FROM subscriptions
WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-01-31'
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(subscription_plan_id) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add `count` And `Group by subscription_plan_id`**

> SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(subscription_plan_id), COUNT(subscription_plan_id)
>   as NumSubs FROM subscriptions WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2014-01-01'
>   AND '2014-01-31' GROUP BY subscription_plan_id HAVING COUNT(subscription_plan_id) >
>   1;